# Why does `this` not console from function context in this snippet?

Tags: javascript, this, javascript-objects

I was reading Kyle Simpson's YDKJS about the `this` keyword.

There was an example illustrating how the `this` binding my be lost.

Here's the example

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}

function doFoo(fn) {
    // `fn` is just another reference to `foo`

    fn(); // <-- call-site!
}

var obj = {
    a: 2,
    foo: foo
};

var a = "oops, global"; // `a` also property on global object

doFoo( obj.foo ); // "oops, global”
```

If `this` depends on the the callsite, if I rewrite the example in the following way

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}

function doFoo(fn) {
    fn();
}

var obj = {
    a: 2,
    foo: foo
};

var obj2 = {
    a: 3,
    doFoo: doFoo
}


var a = "oops, global"; // `a` also property on global object

obj2.doFoo(obj.foo); // logs "oops, global”
```

In my example the callsite is function `doFn`, and its context is `obj2`. Why is the global `this` still printed?

Comment: `doFoo( obj.foo.bind(obj) );`

Comment: I've edited the question. Hope my question is a little more clear now, what I am looking for is the why.

Comment: The accepted answer to [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/215552) explains the why in great detail. If there's something you don't understand about how the answers to the duplicates answer your question, edit your question with the specific questions you have. You may want to reference the parts of the answers you're having trouble with (if any).